# Video embed on facebook wall does not play when on https

Tags: facebook, https, embed

We have set up the open graph tags on our pages to embed a video on the facebook wall of the user that shares the page.

When the video is clicked when on http:// it will play perfectly. 
When the video is clicked when on https:// (e.g. set up in the privacy settings) only the screenshot is displayed, and links to the shared page.

The situation can be produced by sharing the following URL: http://sizzer.nl/en/work/show/id/81/ and watch it on your wall when using http:// and https://

Vimeo and YouTube videos do play when watched on https

Should we change the headers on our servers or is there a partnership between Facebook and Youtube / Vimeo that allows them show video when the users wall is shown on https?

Comment: I see that you figured this out. Looking at your `<meta>` tags it looks like you only had to change the `og:video` tag contents to `https` resources - your `og:image`, `og:url`, etc. are still over `http`. Did you have to do anything alongside of this to get it to work? I tried effectively the same thing, but am not getting the embedding to work over `https`.

Comment: I may have figured it out. I'm using JWPlayer with a `file` query parameter URL that's not https. I didn't think this would be a problem, but switching the `file` over to https worked.

Answer (score 1):

To set up a HTTPS source for the video you need to specify the `og:video:secure_url` tag and point it to the HTTPS source for the video.

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo
It was announced in yesterdays blog post too: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/602/

Answer (score 0):

try `<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="http://..." />`

Comment: Thanks Paul, we will test this asap.

Comment: Update: Chrome will no longer validate SSL certificates when video player redirects to http sources when embedded on https

Comment: Open Graph no longer accepts urls with a prefix of http for og:video:secure_url, they must start with https

Answer (score 0):

The secure_url tag does not work, nor do Youtube and Vimeo use it.  I've only managed to resolve this by serving content over https

Comment: The solution is to only include https urls. This is the most effective approach I have seen so far.